# error connecting pentaho with Jena Fuseki

Tags: jdbc, pentaho, jena

I'm trying to create a conecction from pentaho (7.0.0.0-25) to Jena (fuseki 2.4.1), using "connection type: SPARKSQL" (and localhost, port, and DBname) in pentaho, and I get this error:

```
Error connecting to database [test]         :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class     org.apache.hive.jdbc.SparkSqlSimbaDriver)
No suitable driver found for     jdbc:spark://localhost:3030/testSKMO;AuthMech=0;SocketTimeout=10


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class     org.apache.hive.jdbc.SparkSqlSimbaDriver)
No suitable driver found for     jdbc:spark://localhost:3030/testSKMO;AuthMech=0;SocketTimeout=10


at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:472)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:370)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:341)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:331)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2795)
at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:598)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:43)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:137)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:80)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:47)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:116)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:60)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.newConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:475)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.newConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:462)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.doubleClickedInTree(Spoon.java:3066)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.doubleClickedInTree(Spoon.java:3036)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.access$2200(Spoon.java:361)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon$26.widgetDefaultSelected(Spoon.java:6169)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1359)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7990)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9290)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:685)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class     org.apache.hive.jdbc.SparkSqlSimbaDriver)
No suitable driver found for     jdbc:spark://localhost:3030/testSKMO;AuthMech=0;SocketTimeout=10

at     org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:585)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:456)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for     jdbc:spark://localhost:3030/testSKMO;AuthMech=0;SocketTimeout=10
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at     org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:571)
    ... 49 more

Hostname       :localhost
Port           :3030
Database name  :testSKMO
```

I have download .jar files "jena-jdbc-driver-bundle-3.1.0.jar" (contains driver to Jena connection) and "pentaho-big-data-kettle-plugins-hive.jar" (contains "SparkSQLSimbaDriver" class, that class looks like cause error) and I have tried somethings:

- To put that .jar in Pentaho/data-integration/lib
- To create a new folder Pentaho/data-integration/libext/JDBC and to put .jar in this.

In both cases still getting the same error.

Someone have any idea or hint to solve it?? 
Finally, the question is how I can connect Pentaho with Jena.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To connect Pentaho with Jena you must:

- put "jena-jdbc-driver-bundle-3.1.0.jar" (it contains drivers to connect with Jena) in folder Pentaho/data-integration/lib/
- use a connection type "Generic" (in Pentaho, when you create a new connection). Probably, that is the problem's key
- define, in this connection, "jdbc:jena:remote:update=http://localhost:3030/name_of_dataset/update" (in my case) like custom connection URL and "org.apache.jena.jdbc.remote.RemoteEndpointDriver" like driver class

...and... go!!